# What does the square symbol means in pm2?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, pm2

It is confusing for me to get the meaning of the symbol when I run the below command:

```
pm2 status
```

It shows a table. The confusing part is the square symbol which I have marked in the below picture

[image: pm2 status table]

What does it actually mean? Are three instances of index server running or something like that?

Comment: That looks like the Unicode replacement symbol, indicating your terminal cannot display the proper character there.  [This doc](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#list-managed-applications) shows an arrow in a similar looking column, which might mean restarts or something, but I can't find any other documentation on the topic. I hope someone more familiar can help further.

Comment: @FlimzyYes I can confirm it's ```process restart counter```

Comment: @Fozie Try resetting it to 0 with this command ```pm2 reset <process>```

Comment: Thanks both of you

Comment: @MAS - Please post an answer.

Comment: It should be showing `↺` there.  If I run this from cmd.exe on windows I get that character, but if I run it from a terminal in vscode I see `↺` correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting @Flimzy comment:

> That looks like the Unicode replacement symbol, indicating your terminal cannot display the proper character there.This [doc](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/#list-managed-applications) shows an arrow in a similar looking column.

This column/value refer to the process's number of restarts which have occurred since the first run.

To see it in actions, the following command does restart the process `pm2 restart <process-name|id>`, which will increase the restarts counter by 1.